# Changing variable in superclass from subclass using swift in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, inheritance, subclass, superclass

I have one superclass named Conversion and bunch of subclasses, i.e. Weight. I want an array of type String to be taken from the subclass and used in the superclass. I might be off on the inheritance part here; Can't go from subclass to superclass?

However, I decided to ask anyways, just in case.

```
class Conversion: UIViewController{
var List = [""]
//code that uses variable List
}

class Weight: Conversion{
var List = ["Milligram", "Gram", "Hectogram", "Kilogram", "Ton", "Ounce", "Pound", "Stone"]
//Somehow replace variable List in Conversion superclass
```

In advance, thank you for your time.

Comment: Why even redeclare the variable in the subclass? You can just set the inherited version in the init function.

Comment: Can you give me an example? I've tried various different ways with init(), without succeeding.

Comment: In the subclass: `init() { List = ["Milligram", "Gram", "Hectogram", "Kilogram", "Ton", "Ounce", "Pound", "Stone"] }`. Don't do `var List = …` because that's declaring another variable in a different scope.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things amiss here. First off, if you are going to try and use inheritance here, don't tie these classes into either the controller or the MainClass hierarchy, rather, make them independent and then use them in the controller or better yet, start by using them in a unit test.

As to whether inheritance applies in this case at all, surely it could. For instance, you could say a Converter could be a generalized or abstract performer of a specific function, and specific conversions require different implementations. For instance, a currency converter might have to consult external tables while a weight converter needs merely math. Hiding implementation details is a primary purpose of OO design.

However, the main reason to derive things from a common base, or to have them implement a common protocol, is so that *you can treat things that are different as if they are the same*. When people ask why there are interfaces in Java, that's usually the best answer. In Swift, you have Protocols. I am straining to see why a weight and a currency converter would, for instance, benefit from being operable through a common interface.

Further, for this to really work, you would need genericity. You are showing strings here, but those are really not what you want. Any Measure is going to be a value and a unit. So if I take my weight it would be a number and then an indicator of weather that was in Pounds or Kilograms. You will want those to be Enums probably.

Finally, where this would make some sense is if you were wanting to have the option to use different converters for the same operation. For instance, there are many ways to do currency conversion. You could define a Protocol `CurrencyConverter` and then have multiple implementations of that protocol, which would be replaceable at runtime. The idea there is that you would have the code manipulating the converter through a common protocol and different implementations could be added without altering any of the code that is using the component.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Inheritance.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH17-ID196)

> Where this is appropriate, you access the superclass version of a
>   method, property, or subscript by using the `super` prefix:
>
> - An overridden method named `someMethod()` can call the superclass version of `someMethod()` by calling `super.someMethod()` within the overriding method implementation.
> - An overridden property called `someProperty` can access the superclass version of someProperty as `super.someProperty` within the overriding getter or setter implementation.
> - An overridden subscript for `someIndex` can access the superclass version of the same subscript as `super[someIndex]` from within the overriding subscript implementation.

You should prefix the subclass property with `override` to get this functionality, should you need it.

Note that you generally do not need to do this, instead you can just inherit the property from the superclass and initialize it in your own `init()`:

```
class Conversion {
  var List = [""]
}

class Weight: Conversion {
  override init() {
    super.init()
    List = ["Milligram", "Gram", "Hectogram", "Kilogram", "Ton", "Ounce", "Pound", "Stone"]
  }
}
```

Even better might be to use a protocol instead:

```
protocol Conversion {
  static var list:[String] { get }
}

class Weight: Conversion {
  static let list = ["Milligram", "Gram", "Hectogram", "Kilogram", "Ton", "Ounce", "Pound", "Stone"]
}
```